# Unable to store data in LocalStorage in an To-Do-List app

Tags: html, jquery-mobile

I am trying to build an simple To-Do-List app using jQuery-Mobile with Local Storage support but i tried in manyways i am failing while storing the data in local storage and displaying them in a List here is the code which i have made any help to correct my code will be appreciated

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
    <title>ToDoL</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.4.3.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.mobile-1.4.3.min.js"></script>     
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
    var tasks[];       
        $(document).on("pagecreate","#todoadderpage",function(){
            var appendTaskToList=function(val){
                $("#todolist").append("<li>"+val+"</li>");
            }
            var addTask=function(){
                //alert("Hello");
                var val=$("#todotitle").val();
                tasks.push(val);
                localStorage['tasks']=JSON.stringify(tasks);
                appendTaskToList(val);
            }
            $("#todoadderokbtn").click(addTask);

        });
    </script>             
</head>
<body>
<section id="landing" data-role="page">
    <header data-role="header" data-position="fixed" data-theme="b">
        <h1>ToDoL Logo</h1>
    </header>
    <article data-role="main" class="ui-content">
        <center>        
        <a href="#todoadderpage" id="adderbtn" data-role="button" data-mini="true" data-inline="true" data-rel="dialog" data-transition="pop">Add To-Do</a>
        <input type="button" id="remover" value="Remove Completed Task" data-mini="true" data-inline="true"/>
        </center>
        <hr/>
        <ul id="todolist" data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
            <li data-role="list-divider">Your To-Do-List</li>
           <li id="notodolist"><p>You Don't have any pending task</p></li>
        </ul>
        <br/><br/><br/>

    </article>
    <footer data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" data-theme="b">
        <h1>&copy Reserved By Dinesh Raja</h1>
    </footer>
</section> 
<section id="todoadderpage" data-role="page" data-close-btn="none">
    <header data-role="header" data-position="fixed" data-theme="b">
        <h1>New To-Do</h1>
    </header>
    <article data-role="main" class="ui-content">
    <form id="todoadderform">
        <div data-role="fieldcontain">
            <label for="todotitle">Title</label>
            <input type="text" id="todotitle" data-mini="true"/><br/><br/><br/>            
            <center>                    
            <a href="#" id="todoaddercancelbtn" data-role="button" data-mini="true" data-inline="true" data-rel="back">Cancel</a>
            <input type="button" id="todoadderokbtn" value="Ok" data-mini="true" data-inline="true"/>
            </center>
        </div>
    </form>
    </article>
</section>
<section id="todoviewerpage" data-role="page" data-close-btn="none">
    <header data-role="header">
        <h1>To-Do-Viewer</h1>
    </header>
    <article data-role="main" class="ui-content">
        <center>
            <label for="tododata"></label>
        </center>
        <p id="tododata"></p>
        <center>
            <a href="#" id="todoviewerokbtn" data-role="button" data-rel="back">Ok</a>
        </center>
    </article>
</section>  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Its not storing the values in the localstorage which i am entering in the textbox and its not being updated in the List(ul).

Comment: When you test w/ Remote Debugging, do you see an error? If you console.log(JSON.stringify(localeStorage['tasks'])), do you see anything?

Comment: I din't test with remote debugging in Firebug plugin i just checked the localstorage contents and its empty
console.log(JSON.stringify(localeStorage['tasks']));

This is not generating any change

Comment: I have found the bug :( its an silly mistake which i have made in the first line of the script var tasks[] instead of var tasks=[];

Thanks for your help Raymond Camden

P.S:I have read an article from your site longback while i was surfing some information about Phonegap :)

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
<title>ToDoL</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.4.3.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.mobile-1.4.3.min.js"></script>     
<script type="text/javascript"> 
var tasks[];       
    $(document).on("pagecreate","#todoadderpage",function(){
        var appendTaskToList=function(val){
            $("#todolist").append("<li>"+val+"</li>");
        }
        var addTask=function(){
            //alert("Hello");
            var val=$("#todotitle").val();
            tasks.push(val);
            local-Storage['tasks']=JSON.stringify(tasks);
            appendTaskToList(val);
        }
        $("#todoadderokbtn").click(addTask);

    });
</script>             
</head>
<body>
<section id="landing" data-role="page">
<header data-role="header" data-position="fixed" data-theme="b">
    <h1>ToDoL Logo</h1>
</header>
<article data-role="main" class="ui-content">
    <center>        
    <a href="#todoadderpage" id="adderbtn" data-role="button" data-mini="true" data-                inline="true" data-rel="dialog" data-transition="pop">Add To-Do</a>
    <input type="button" id="remover" value="Remove Completed Task" data-mini="true"         data-inline="true"/>
    </center>
    <hr/>
    <ul id="todolist" data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
        <li data-role="list-divider">Your To-Do-List</li>
       <li id="notodolist"><p>You Don't have any pending task</p></li>
    </ul>
    <br/><br/><br/>

</article>
<footer data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" data-theme="b">
    <h1>&copy Reserved By Dinesh Raja</h1>
</footer>
</section> 
<section id="todoadderpage" data-role="page" data-close-btn="none">
<header data-role="header" data-position="fixed" data-theme="b">
    <h1>New To-Do</h1>
</header>
<article data-role="main" class="ui-content">
<form id="todoadderform">
    <div data-role="fieldcontain">
        <label for="todotitle">Title</label>
        <input type="text" id="todotitle" data-mini="true"/><br/><br/><br/>            
        <center>                    
        <a href="#" id="todoaddercancelbtn" data-role="button" data-mini="true"     data-inline="true" data-rel="back">Cancel</a>
        <input type="button" id="todoadderokbtn" value="Ok" data-mini="true" data-inline="true"/>
        </center>
    </div>
</form>
</article>
</section>
<section id="todoviewerpage" data-role="page" data-close-btn="none">
<header data-role="header">
    <h1>To-Do-Viewer</h1>
</header>
<article data-role="main" class="ui-content">
    <center>
        <label for="tododata"></label>
    </center>
    <p id="tododata"></p>
    <center>
        <a href="#" id="todoviewerokbtn" data-role="button" data-rel="back">Ok</a>
    </center>
</article>
</section>  
</body>
</html>
```